# files are not showing in project structure under Android tab in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, project-structure

File (Project) structure is stuck at loading in flutter project under Android tab only in Android Studio(4.2.1).

Thank you!

[Please check this image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oia0b.png)

Comment: picture you uploaded in not available

Comment: Please check now

Comment: change that Android to project 
and do invalidate Cache and restart

Comment: Let me try, will inform you.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not open flutter project in Android tab,
If you want to open android files in Android tab then you need to open Android folder in another android studio from flutter project and then you can show your files.

Comment: But when I created project, file structure was visible that time

Comment: Yes it was, because flutter project file structure shown in "Project" -> "Project" tab.
Not in "Project" -> "Android" Tab.